# How should I find out the bounds of the symbolic solution, since the numerical solution is 1 , but the symbolic solution cannot show 1?

Tags: symbolic

There is a symbolic solution which doesn't show 1, but when replaced variales with values, there is 1.

```mathematica
a1 = {ax, ay};
b1 = {bx, by};
c1 = {cx, cy};
d1 = {dx, dy};
ab = Simplify[y - InterpolatingPolynomial[{a1, b1}, x] == 0];
bc = Simplify[y - InterpolatingPolynomial[{b1, c1}, x] == 0];
ac = Simplify[y - InterpolatingPolynomial[{a1, c1}, x] == 0];
ad = Simplify[y - InterpolatingPolynomial[{a1, d1}, x] == 0];
bd = Simplify[y - InterpolatingPolynomial[{b1, d1}, x] == 0];
cd = Simplify[y - InterpolatingPolynomial[{c1, d1}, x] == 0];
g1 = First[{x, y} /. Solve[ab && cd, {x, y}]];
f1 = First[{x, y} /. Solve[bc && ad, {x, y}]];
e1 = First[{x, y} /. Solve[ac && bd, {x, y}]];
lad = EuclideanDistance[a1, d1];
lbd = EuclideanDistance[b1, d1];
lcd = EuclideanDistance[c1, d1];
lde1 = EuclideanDistance[e1, d1];
ldf1 = EuclideanDistance[f1, d1];
ldg1 = EuclideanDistance[g1, d1];
lfa1 = EuclideanDistance[f1, a1];
ldg1/(ldg1 + lcd) + ldf1/(ldf1 + lad) + lde1/(lde1 + lbd)
```

gives:
[image]

However,

```mathematica
ldg1/(ldg1 + lcd) + ldf1/(ldf1 + lad) + lde1/(lde1 + lbd) /. {ax -> 2,
   ay -> 2, bx -> 3, by -> 3, cx -> 4, cy -> 5, dx -> 5/2, dy -> 5/2}
```

gives **1**.

So, there is bounds of symbolic solution, or the first will output **1**. How can I find it?